# attention decoder implementation in tensorflow r1.0

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am confused by the attention decoder implementation in tensorflow r1.0. The original code can be found here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.0/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/attention_decoder_fn.py.

Here is the part of code that I am confused about:

```
def decoder_fn(time, cell_state, cell_input, cell_output, context_state):
    if cell_state is None:  # first call, return encoder_state
        cell_state = encoder_state

        # init attention
        attention = _init_attention(encoder_state)
    else:
        # construct attention
        attention = attention_construct_fn(cell_output, attention_keys,
                                       attention_values)
        # in the doc, they said they won't change the cell_output
        cell_output = attention

    # combine cell_input and attention
    next_input = array_ops.concat([cell_input, attention], 1)

    return (None, cell_state, next_input, cell_output, context_state)
```

In my understanding, the decoder receives states from last time step and produce a hidden state and a output. Attention is created based on the previous hidden state of RNN and the current input. Our final output of decoder is the all of the outputs produced by RNN during each time step.

However, it seems like in tensorflow the decoder returns the attention as output and in each time step it uses output of RNN as input to calculate the attention.

Is the implementation in tensorflow wrong? But practically, this implementation (in tensorflow) performs better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how the attention based model works. Unlike predicting the output only with the previous vector(ht) here there's another vector called context vector (Ct). So the final hidden vector before applying the softmax will be a concatenation of ht and Ct. Here Ct is made of multiplying each hidden state in the encoder multiplied by some kind of attention. It's like how much each hidden layer vector in encoder has an impact on the decoder output that we are going to predict. This scalar is called the attention. This attention is a trainable parameter. There are many ways to obtain this value. So this value is rely on hidden state vectors in encoder and the current hidden vector in the decoder.
[This slides will give you a good understanding](https://www.slideshare.net/KeonKim/attention-mechanisms-with-tensorflow)

I think

[image]